# Current Location Problem using MKMapView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am integrating map feature into my application. I have displayed the current location. In my problem is, i am developing two applications and displayed the current location. But both the applications displayed the current location in different location and different view in the map. See my screenshots[image]   [image]

Both the screenshots are taken by simulator with two applications and it shows the different Map view frame. But i have used the same code for that.(This happens in device also, show the different place with the map frame). I donno why the map view frame is changed? I have created the map view frame in XIB. And i have included the required frameworks and switched on the location services. Why the Map frame view change? It's weird to me.

Here my sample code is,

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {

       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];

       self.locationManager.delegate = self; 

       [mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

```
  - (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {      
    MKCoordinateRegion region1;
    
    region1.center = newLocation.coordinate;

    //Change the Zoom level of the current location

    //region1.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;//0.0001

    //region1.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1; //0.0001

    mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

    //[mapview setRegion:region1 animated:TRUE];

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    }
```

I hope, the first screen shot map view frame is correct. Because i have passed the map view co-ordinates(North East, North West, South East and South West) to the server. If the frame size is wrong, i will get the wrong user details from the server.
Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The lines in your `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` that are commented out are required for the map view to be updated. You need the call to `[mapView setRegion:animated]` in order to change the view region. Is your code definitely the same in both applications?

I assume that you know that in the simulator the current location is always the Apple headquarters in Cupertino, as shown in your first screenshot.